# How do I get an object ID of a user, by display name, from Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am creating a Power App which is supposed to modify custom attributes on users on an Azure B2C tenant. However, the only way to update said users is by a Patch call referencing "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/object-id" (which I am calling via a Power Automate flow). Since these are b2c users, their actual UPN does not match their email. I need to find a way to get this object ID beforehand so I can pass the appropriate patch call. Any tips? Thanks!

I tried using an Azure AD connector in Power Automate flow using the email of the user, but that is not their actual upn.

Comment: What if there is more than one user with the same display name? What do you mean by that UPN UPN does not match their email?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=displayName eq 'USER DISPLAY NAME'&$select=id
```

will return user id